# Keycloak with spring boot NoSuchMethodError org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSessionManager()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, jetty, keycloak

I'm currently trying to get Keycloak bearer only to work with a spring boot application. I've followed the docs but I continue to get a NoSuchMethodError when I try to hit any of my endpoints. It seems similar to this [keycloak issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4537). Based on that it looks like it should be working in all of the latest builds. 
I've followed [this tutorial](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/) for the most part.

I have the project [here](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d77?at=master) for reference. ([POM](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d774da3f12ab43a7eddc19d07e6b41c/pom.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), [KeycloakConfiguration](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d774da3f12ab43a7eddc19d07e6b41c/src/main/resources/application.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#application.yml-26:40))

Starting the app using `mvn spring-boot:run`

When hitting any route (in this example `http://localhost:5767/health`) I get [this error](https://gist.github.com/RingOfStorms/73b1045e3acc8965c851f8a1046907bd):

```
{
    "timestamp": 1514942790219,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
    "message": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSessionManager()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager;",
    "path": "/health"
}
```

Which prints [the following](https://gist.github.com/RingOfStorms/1d27cc1d98d7d419e345eb79b7099433) in the app's console:

```
2018-01-02 19:22:35.926  INFO 6201 --- [           main] com.ringofstorms.jservice.Application    : Started Application in 9.381 seconds (JVM running for 13.906)
2018-01-02 19:26:30.176  WARN 6201 --- [tp1664999292-17] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /health

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSessionManager()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager;
    at org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator.createSessionManagement(KeycloakJettyAuthenticator.java:66) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.core.AbstractKeycloakJettyAuthenticator.validateRequest(AbstractKeycloakJettyAuthenticator.java:292) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483) ~[jetty-security-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Using Keycloak-3.4.2.Final (Ran with `./Keycloak-3.4.2.Final/bin/standalone`)
[Here is my current maven dependency tree.](https://gist.github.com/RingOfStorms/590b4b714deacb67b1c7438714b8df54)
[And current environment](https://gist.github.com/RingOfStorms/9c64101788bbb969dfae66b98697c840) (Refer to POM in repo for dependency versions)

Right now you can see I have the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` [depdenency commented out](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d774da3f12ab43a7eddc19d07e6b41c/pom.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#pom.xml-83:86), and am attempting to just do the security [through the application.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d774da3f12ab43a7eddc19d07e6b41c/src/main/resources/application.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#application.yml-36:40) like the [tutorial](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/#Defining%20Keycloak's%20configuration) does BEFORE it introduces the adapter and java configuration (which is [also commented out](https://bitbucket.org/RingOfStorms/jservice-share/src/f6effaa12d774da3f12ab43a7eddc19d07e6b41c/src/main/java/com/ringofstorms/jservice/configuration/Keycloak.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Keycloak.java-15:17)).

Am I missing some weird depdency conflict with Jetty versions? All the Jetty versions in the depdency tree are the same. So I am a bit lost on what is casuing this issue.

**My desired behavior is** to get 403's on all routes unless I pass a valid bearer token through the headers from whatever client I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a dependency conflict. The `Request` class in `org.eclipse.jetty.server` of version 9.4.7 doesn't have a method `getSessionManager()`. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.7.v20170914/index.html?org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html). Whereas, in the earlier version [9.3.2](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.3.20.v20170531/index.html?org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html), this method was present.

So,Can you try by using 9.3.2 version of Jetty?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am able to downgrade the jetty version as that is not a dependency of my project but of the spring boot dependencies. I'll give a go at trying to downgrade the `spring-boot-starter-jetty` to an earlier version without downgrading all of spring boot, as I'd rather be on the current version. I'll update my progress when I get around to trying it. I suppose I will also see about updating the keycloak adapter if this is the case.  I had thought that the depdency would have been fixed based on the status of the ticket https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4537 though

Comment: I was able to get it to work by forcing all my jetty dependencies to use 9.3.x builds. I submitted another ticket to keycloak and we'll see about fixing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot keycloak starter doesn't work with Jetty 9.4 There is an open bug: 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-9080